# Iteration using Mathematica

Tags: iteration, wolfram-mathematica, equation, equation-solving

I need a way to implement iteration process in Mathematica of the form:

[image: Iteration]

N is constant, S is also constant.

Comment: Parameter i and j go from 1 to some value r. I know how to implement iterative process in Mathematica, but i don't know what should I do when I have this sum over another index j.

Comment: you need some initial condition (`n=0`)

Comment: Initial condition is a^{0}_{i}=0.

Comment: then all the rest will just be `Tan[S/ N Pi]`

Comment: Re. conditions on indices: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25882/how-do-you-put-conditions-on-indices-in-a-sum